# Remove a Style Tag from WP Theme

Tags: css

Am relatively new to the world of websites/coding and not sure how to remove an HTML style tag from my wordpress theme.

I need to remove the tag that's in bold - but I don't know where to find it. Already looked on the editor, but the code looks nothing like what I was told to remove.

```
html class="no-js" lang="en-US" **style="overflow:hidden;"** data-scroll="scroll"
```

Where can I find this tag?

Would appreciate any help whatsoever!

Thanks! 
Kate

Answer (score 1):

The `<html>` tag is probably written in your theme's header.php file, but you should avoid editing it directly as any change you make will be overwritten if the theme is ever updated.

The specific part you are asking to remove is CSS, but you don't need to edit the theme to make CSS changes. Instead you can put your own CSS in *Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS*.

To override this particular CSS, use this:

```
html {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

`visible` is the default for this property, so setting it to that is the same as removing it. The `!important` is required as it's the only way to override an inline rule according to the [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) rules in CSS.